# What does this block of code mean?

Tags: java

What does the second block below run() in the anonymous class new Runnable() { that has no identifier or declaration preceding it mean:

```
        public BackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable)
        {
            super(new Runnable() {

                final Runnable val$runnable;

                public void run()
                {
                    Process.setThreadPriority(10);
                    runnable.run();
                }


                {
                    runnable = runnable1;
                    super();
                }
            });
        }
```

Edit: yes it is decompiled code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an [*instance initializer*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6) - called as part of the constructor. In an anonymous inner class, you can't explicitly declare a constructor, so instance initializers are sometimes used instead. In this case it's pretty pointless, as the `run` method could just use `runnable` directly - it would still be captured at the same time.

(This code doesn't look like it's complete or valid, actually - given that the instance initializer mentions `runnable1` which doesn't appear anywhere else. I'd also not expect the instance initializer to include a `super()` call. Is this possibly decompiled code?)

Comment: As far as I know you cannot have a `super()` call in an instance initializer, so the code as shown above doesn't compile. It certainly looks like decompiled code.

Answer (score 2):

It's an initialization block. It gets compiled into every constructor.

See "Initializing Instance Members" in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).